# How to connect two separate folders into the same GitHub repository?

Tags: linux, github, merge, repository

I have already made a GitHub repository with a `folder1`, but I have a `../etc/etc/folder2` that I would like to add into the same repository because they both are a part of the same project.

As you can see these two folders are not super close to each other, but they are in the same linux file system. How can I add `folder2` to my existing GitHub repository that contains `folder1`?

Answer (score 1):

What I ended up doing was creating the repository in the root directory.

I created a .gitignore file to ignore all files except the two folders that I wanted in the repository.

```
## Ignore everything...
*

## Except...
folder1
folder1/*
path/to/folder2
path/to/folder2/*
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to, locally on your Linux machine, move or copy the folder2 in your local cloned repository, add and commit.

Then you can push, in order to see `folder2` in your remote GitHub repository.

---

The alternative is:

- make a Git repository in `../etc/etc/folder2`, push it to a separate GitHub repo `folder2`
- reference the remote GitHub repository `folder2` as a **[submodule](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitsubmodules)** in your first local cloned repository

That is:

```
cd /path/to/folder1
git submodule add -b main -- https://github.com/<me>/folder2
```

That way, you have the repo `folder2` referenced by your main repository.

If you change anything in folder2 (original path), add, commit and push.

Then, from the first local cloned repository, `git submodule update --remote` is enough to update the `folder2` submodule content.

Comment: This circumstance is unique because for assignment purposes I need to have folder2 where it is. Would I have to make a new repository and merge the two?

Comment: @cquick123 Can you duplicate it?

Comment: @cquick123 I have edited the answer with a possible alternative, which keeps `folder2` where it is.

Comment: I can duplicate it, and that's my last ditch effort. I just wanted to see if it were possible to keep them both in their respective areas while being in the same repository.

Comment: @cquick123 Yes, it is. I have edited the answer to describe how it is possible to keep them in their respective areas, while being in the same repository.

Comment: thank you. I would upvote, but my account doesn't have the clout